# How to keep track of a global index within an MPI_Scatter(...) function?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am working on an MPI program in which process 0 reads a `.raw` file, places it in a pointer array, and distribute it to other processes so they can each do work.  I am currently distributing sections of the pointer array by using `MPI_Scatter` which seems to be working.

The problem:
The calculations to do on each sub array requires knowing what its *global* index is.  Currently I only know how to go over its local index.  Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <mpi.h>

#define MCW MPI_COMM_WORLD

const int WIDTH = 1300;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

//work function that requires the *global* x,y coordinate of the file
float calc_vorticity(int x, int y, int width, int height, float* vector_field) {
    float d_x = 0.01;
    float d_y = 0.01;
    uint32_t index = y * width + x;

    int start_x = (x == 0) ? 0 : x - 1;
    int end_x = (x == width - 1) ? x : x + 1;
    int start_y = (y == 0) ? 0 : y - 1;
    int end_y = (y == height - 1) ? y : y + 1;
    uint32_t duidx = (start_y * width + end_x) * 2;
    uint32_t dvidx = (end_y * width + start_x) * 2;
    std::pair<double, double> fdu(vector_field[duidx], vector_field[duidx + 1]);
    std::pair<double, double> fdv(vector_field[dvidx], vector_field[dvidx + 1]);
    std::pair<double, double> vec0(vector_field[index * 2], vector_field[index * 2 + 1]);
    float duy = (fdu.second - vec0.second) / (d_x * (end_x - start_x));
    float dvx = (fdv.first - vec0.first) / (d_y * (end_y - start_y));

    return duy - dvx;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); //initialize MPI
    MPI_Comm_rank(MCW, &rank); //Assign each processor a rank
    MPI_Comm_size(MCW, &size); //Assign the size

    //allocate the space
    float* vector_field = new float[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2];
    
    //have rank 0 read in image
    if(!rank) {
        FILE* file = fopen("../data/cyl2d_1300x600_float32[2].raw", "r");
        fread(vector_field, sizeof(float), WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    //create buffer of data & catch all processes up to this point
    float* buffer = new float[(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2) / size];
    MPI_Barrier(MCW);

    //broadcast the array to other ranks
    MPI_Scatter(
        vector_field, //array being sent out that resides on root process
        (WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2) / size, //number of items to send
        MPI_FLOAT, //type of items sent
        buffer, //buffer of data that holds number of items in sent array
        (WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2) / size, //number of items to be recieved
        MPI_FLOAT, //type of items recieved
        0, //originating process
        MCW //communicator
    );

    //allocate space for results
    //Note that we only need half the size of buffer as vorticity is represented with only 1 float
    float* vorticities = new float[(WIDTH * HEIGHT) / size];
    MPI_Barrier(MCW);

    //calculate value for each cell
    
    // !!! Problem here !!!
    /* Call calc_vorticity(...) sending the current **global** x/y coordinate */
    /*
    Serial implementation call looks like this:

    for (int i=0; i<WIDTH; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<HEIGHT; j++){
        vorticities[j*WIDTH+i] = vorticity(i, j, WIDTH, HEIGHT, vector_field);
    }
    }
    */

    //assure all processes are caught up
    MPI_Barrier(MCW);

    //have process 0 write to output file
    if(!rank) {
        FILE* output = fopen("../data/vorticities_dist.raw", "w");
        fwrite(vorticities, sizeof(float), WIDTH * HEIGHT, output);
        fclose(output);
    }

    //delete used memory
    delete[] vector_field;
    delete[] vorticities;

    //Finalize & exit
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 1;
}
```

I've looked at a lot of MPI_Gather Docs, and I don't think Scatter/Gather is the answer as you cannot also broadcast the global indexes with that pointer array.  I was also tossing the idea around of creating my own object which has 2 elements, `num` & `global_index`.  This way I could broadcast an array of objects which carry their global index with them, though I don't know how to scatter custom data types.

Comment: on rank `n`, `buffer[i]` is `vector_field[n * (WIDTH * HEIGHT * 2) / size + i]` on rank `0`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 
This assumes that order is preserved in MPI_Scatter?  For example if I have an array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] and I scatter this array to 4 processes, process 0 will have [0, 1, 2], process 1 will have [3, 4, 5], etc?

Comment: This only assumes `MPI_Scatter()` is correctly implemented by your MPI library: https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node97.htm